# Proof $\frac{\sin(ax)}{x} \rightarrow a$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ in the context of a Laplace Transformation

Tags: limits, laplace-transform

I'm finding it difficult to get my head around

$\frac{\sin(ax)}{x} \rightarrow a$ as $x \rightarrow 0,$

however for the Laplace transform of this function,

$\mathcal{L} \{ \frac{\sin(ax)}{x} \} = \arctan(\frac{a}{s}),$

surely, $\arctan(\frac{a}{s}) \rightarrow 0$ as $s \rightarrow \infty$?

But to retain the behaviour seen in the prior limit, as

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ \frac{a}{s} \} = a$,

we would require the nonsensical situation of

$\arctan(\frac{a}{s}) \rightarrow \frac{a}{s}$ as $s \rightarrow \infty.$

Does this create an issue for our description of this function as $t \rightarrow 0$?

Is there a relationship between $s$ and $a$ that prevents us from taking this limit? I feel like I am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: The assertion $\lim_{s\to\infty}\arctan\left(\frac as\right)=\frac as$ doesn't make sense. There is no way that there is a $s$ in the value of that limit. Where did you get that from?

Comment: That is my problem, that there should be no $s$ dependence in the limit, and yet if we wish to recover the behaviour we see prior to the Laplace transform in the $t$ limit then we would need such a thing (which is clearly wrong). I'll edit to clear up any confusion.

Comment: There are other big problems. The major problem I see is that $\lim_{s\to\infty}F(s)$ simply has nothing to do with $\lim_{t\to0}f(t)$.

Comment: Could you please expand? I thought the final value theorem mean that it did?

Comment: That would imply one could truncate a series expanded like $\sum ( \frac{s}{a})^{n} f(s)$ after transforming a series back from Laplace space without making any assumptions on $s$ or $t$. The only assumptions you would be making would be on $f(t)$, its derivatives, and their relationship with $a$. Which is interesting if correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The final value theorem for Laplace's transform actually states:

$$
\lim_{s\to \infty} sF(s) = \lim_{t\to 0^+} f(t)
$$

Thus:
$$
\lim_{s\to \infty} s \left[\text{sgn}(a) \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan \left( \frac{s}{a} \right) \right] = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin(at)}{t}
$$

Check the result for the Laplace transform [with Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lapalce+transform+sin(a*t)%2Ft).

The limit above for $s$ can be computed with L'Hopital's rule [and yields $a$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+s+to+infinity+s*pi%2F2+-+s*atan%5Bs%2Fa%5D+assuming+a%3E0), but that I guess is possibly pointless when the limit for the sine is being put into question.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: Out of interest, does this mean that if we were to expand this function into a series, it would converge on $a$ faster than it would on $s$ or $t$?

Comment: If you are talking about $\sin(at)/t$ ... You would also need to specify the notion to assess the velocity of convergence. Also, I would think the series would converge faster depending on the values chosen for either $t$ and $a$.